# Getting a users username in get_user_meta

Tags: user-meta

I am getting people's first and last names this way:

```
$_UFName = get_user_meta($_uid, 'first_name', true);
$_ULName = get_user_meta($_uid, 'last_name', true);
```

where

```
$_uid
```

is the persons id I pulled in a query from the users table.

How do I get their username? this code:

```
$_UUName = get_user_meta($_uid, 'user_login', true);
```

that is not working. It is blank.

Is there a way to get it from the user meta?

thx,
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The username is not a user meta entry, so you'll probably want to work with a `WP_User` object instead:

```
$user = get_user_by( 'id', $_uid );
echo $user->user_login;
```

Comment: Oh, duh. LOL sorry about that. Stupid of me. Should have slept before working on this.